# CATIA v5 macro open properties

Tags: catia

I have a macro where i add properties to the part.

But i need to open the properties to change a few options (drop list)

How can i make the code to open the part properties and leave it opened (and finish the macro)

my macro ends like this:

'---------------MSG BOX---------------------------

msgbox "PARAMETERS CREATED - CHANGE NECESSARY PROPERTIES ACCORDING SELECTED MATERIAL", , name

partDocument1.Save

Set partDocument1 = CATIA.ActiveDocument

Set product1 = partDocument1.GetItem("")   <<<<--- this one do nothinG

End Sub

Comment: What kind of propertiers? e.g. the properties of a part as the part number?

Comment: Just leave  the properties window open!

Comment: So like you select the part/product in the tree an hit _ALT+enter_?

Comment: yes, that i am using already.
But i am writing some properties with one macro, and i would like to leavethe properties open to write other properties (from a drob box menu) and i want to ensure that the designer will not miss that!

Comment: link for the macro: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y8FpqN8v8nH5yJ9KgAHGdCTIrU_dQCiS/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here an example how to open the properties of a CATPart\CATproduct via StartCommand. Be aware, Startcommands are are language-dependent.

```vb
Sub CATMain()

Dim oDoc as Document
Dim osel as Object 'Selection

Set oDoc = Catia.ActiveDocument
Set oSel = oDoc.Selection

oSel.Clear
oSel.Add oDoc.Product

Catia.StartCommand "Properties"

End Sub
```

Comment: Its workin, but i remove the this two lines:

'Dim oDoc as Document
'Dim osel as Object 'Selection

Comment: @CarlosGoncalves Of course, if you are using catvbs and not catscript.

Comment: Just another question: is possible to create a drop list using CATvbs?

Comment: @CarlosGoncalves No.